# How do I trigger 2 Google Scripts in the same Project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Form that populates a Google Sheet.  I have a project that contains two Google Scripts.  one adds a calendar entry from the data in the Sheet, the other emails certain data to recipients.  I have a trigger in place which works for the Calendar, how do I add a second trigger for the email script?

Google searches show how to add a single trigger.  Older Google searches show an add button on the Triggers page to add another trigger.  I do not have this?

How do I trigger my email script?

Comment: Call the second script from  the calendar.

Comment: You should be able to create more triggers in YourProject > Triggers.

Comment: Thanks TheMaster for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:  As both scripts were inside the same project, I called the second script from the end of the first (that had the working trigger in place).  Works a treat!